# Jpa - Hibernate ManyToMany do many insert into join table

Tags: oracle, hibernate, jpa-2.1

I have follows `ManyToMany` relationship between `WorkDay`(has annotation ManyToMany) and `Event`

> WorkDay entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "WORK_DAY", uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "WORKER_ID", "DAY_ID" }) })
@NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(name = WorkDay.GET_WORK_DAYS_BY_MONTH, query = "select wt from WorkDay wt where wt.worker = :worker and to_char(wt.day.day, 'yyyyMM') = :month) order by wt.day"),
        @NamedQuery(name = WorkDay.GET_WORK_DAY, query = "select wt from WorkDay wt where wt.worker = :worker and wt.day = :day") })
public class WorkDay extends SuperClass {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static final String GET_WORK_DAYS_BY_MONTH = "WorkTimeDAO.getWorkDaysByMonth";
    public static final String GET_WORK_DAY = "WorkTimeDAO.getWorkDay";

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "WORKER_ID", nullable = false)
    private Worker worker;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "DAY_ID", nullable = false)
    private Day day;

    @Column(name = "COMING_TIME")
    @Convert(converter = LocalDateTimeAttributeConverter.class)
    private LocalDateTime comingTime;

    @Column(name = "OUT_TIME")
    @Convert(converter = LocalDateTimeAttributeConverter.class)
    private LocalDateTime outTime;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "STATE", length = 16, nullable = false)
    private WorkDayState state = WorkDayState.NO_WORK;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "WORK_DAY_EVENT", joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "WORK_DAY_ID", nullable = false)}, inverseJoinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "EVENT_ID", nullable = false)})
    @OrderBy(value = "startTime desc")
    private List<Event> events = new ArrayList<>();

    protected WorkDay() {
    }

    public WorkDay(Worker worker, Day day) {
        this.worker = worker;
        this.day = day;
        this.state = WorkDayState.NO_WORK;
    }
}
```

> Event entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EVENT")
public class Event extends SuperClass {

    @Column(name = "DAY", nullable = false)
    @Convert(converter = LocalDateAttributeConverter.class)
    private LocalDate day;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "TYPE_ID", nullable = false)
    private EventType type;

    @Column(name = "TITLE", nullable = false, length = 128)
    private String title;

    @Column(name = "DESCRIPTION", nullable = true, length = 512)
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "START_TIME", nullable = false)
    @Convert(converter = LocalDateTimeAttributeConverter.class)
    private LocalDateTime startTime;

    @Column(name = "END_TIME", nullable = true)
    @Convert(converter = LocalDateTimeAttributeConverter.class)
    private LocalDateTime endTime;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "STATE", nullable = false, length = 16)
    private EventState state;

    protected Event() {
    }
}
```

Attached UI form for clarity

[image]

When I push Clock with run icon first time, it means "create event and start work day" in bean, calling the following methods:

```
public void startEvent() {
    stopLastActiveEvent();
    Event creationEvent = new Event(workDay.getDay().getDay(), selectedEventType, selectedEventType.getTitle(),
            LocalDateTime.now());
    String addEventMessage = workDay.addEvent(creationEvent);
    if (Objects.equals(addEventMessage, "")) {
        em.persist(creationEvent);
        if (workDay.isNoWork()
                && !creationEvent.getType().getCategory().equals(EventCategory.NOT_INFLUENCE_ON_WORKED_TIME)) {
            startWork();
        }
        em.merge(workDay);
    } else {
        Notification.warn("Невозможно создать событие", addEventMessage);
    }
    cleanAfterCreation();
}

public String addEvent(Event additionEvent) {
    if (!additionEvent.getType().getCategory().equals(NOT_INFLUENCE_ON_WORKED_TIME)
            && isPossibleTimeBoundaryForEvent(additionEvent.getStartTime(), additionEvent.getEndTime())) {
        events.add(additionEvent);
        changeTimeBy(additionEvent);
    } else {
        return "Пересечение временых интервалов у событий";
    }
    Collections.sort(events, new EventComparator());
    return "";
}

private void startWork() {
    workDay.setComingTime(workDay.getLastWorkEvent().getStartTime());
    workDay.setState(WorkDayState.WORKING);
}
```

In log I see:

1. insert into event table
2. update work_day table
3. insert into work_day_event table

on UI updated only attached frame. Always looks fine.. current `WorkDay` object have one element in the `events` collection, also all data is inserted into `DB`.. but if this time edit event row

[image]

event row listener:

```
public void onRowEdit(RowEditEvent event) {
    Event editableEvent = (Event) event.getObject();
    LocalDateTime startTime = fixDate(editableEvent.getStartTime(), editableEvent.getDay());
    LocalDateTime endTime = fixDate(editableEvent.getEndTime(), editableEvent.getDay());
    if (editableEvent.getState().equals(END) && startTime.isAfter(endTime)) {
        Notification.warn("Невозможно сохранить изменения", "Время окончания события больше времени начала");
        refreshEvent(editableEvent);
        return;
    }
    if (workDay.isPossibleTimeBoundaryForEvent(startTime, endTime)) {
        editableEvent.setStartTime(startTime);
        editableEvent.setEndTime(endTime);
        workDay.changeTimeBy(editableEvent);
        em.merge(workDay);
        em.merge(editableEvent);
    } else {
        refreshEvent(editableEvent);
        Notification.warn("Невозможно сохранить изменения", "Пересечение временых интервалов у событий");
    }
}
```

to the `work_day_event` insert new row with same `work_day_id` and `event_id` data. And if edit row else do one more insert and etc.. In the result I have several equals rows in `work_day_event` table. Why does this happen?

[link to github project repository(look ver-1.1.0-many-to-many-problem branch)](https://github.com/OnBrains/WorkAssistant/tree/ver-1.1.0-many-to-many-problem)

[image]

Comment: You've got `CascadeType.ALL` for the events into the work day. That means it's not necessary to save the event itself separately. Saving the work day should do the job: `em.merge(workDay);`.

Comment: @XtremeBiker, yes but it's not resoleved my problem

Comment: Have you tried using the separate mapper entity class for the work_day_event?

Comment: Please try to follow http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve rule while asking.

Answer (score 11):

Change `CascadeType.ALL` to `CascadeType.MERGE` for `events` in the `WorkDay entity`

Use this code

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
```

instead of

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
```

---

Do not use `ArrayList`, use `HashSet`. Because `ArrayList` allows duplicates.

For more info about CasecadeType, follow the tutorial:

1. [Hibernate JPA Cascade Types](http://howtodoinjava.com/hibernate/hibernate-jpa-cascade-types/)
2. [Cascading best practices](https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-jpa-and-hibernate-cascade-types/)

Comment: ty for your answer. I have tried to use `CascadeType.MERGE` instead `CascadeType.ALL`, also I have tried to use `Set` but it did not resolve my problem.

Comment: @HAYMbl4 If possible you can share your project through github. I will try to fix your issue.

Comment: @HAYMbl4 You can go through http://viralpatel.net/blogs/hibernate-many-to-many-annotation-mapping-tutorial/ for better understanding.

Comment: I think the problem may be that I'm using `EntityManager` rather than the `ManyToMany`.

Comment: @HAYMbl4 There is same issue happens. Would you please check this link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31738710/update-existing-records-in-hibernate-manytomany-relation and give me update. Then I will try your code.

Comment: I use JTA transaction type and I cant manage session. Also if I do `workDay.getEvents().get(0).equals(editableEvent)` I gote true.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simple solution is to remove the cascade on many to many relationship and do the job manually ! . I see you already doing it redundantly anyway . So try removing you CascadeType.ALL

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
```

[How to persist @ManyToMany relation - duplicate entry or detached entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9821914/how-to-persist-manytomany-relation-duplicate-entry-or-detached-entity)